# Linear Layout with orientation horizontal makes the text invisible when the length increases

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

Android Linear Layout with orientation horizontal makes the next TextViews invisible when the first text's length increases.If the first textview length is more than one line, the remaining textviews are going out of visibility.  I just want to wrap around the text i.e., If the length of the first textview increases the remaining views should come under the first view.

Can I achieve without changing the orientation programmatically?

My Code is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
        app:civ_border_width="5dp"
        app:civ_border="true"
        android:src="@drawable/user"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="3dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/period"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/views"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/period"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hoursago"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_overflow_grey_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm getting the screens as

[image]

Comment: Yes ,You can acheive next textview by using HorizontalScrollView or you can fix the width of first TextView.

Comment: you can try by giving weight to each texview

Comment: though I'm giving weights the text is aligning inside the specified weight. I just want to wrap around the text i.e., If the length of the first textview increases the remaining views should come under the first view

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your linearLayout

```
android:weightSum="1"
```

Then in each of your TextViews add how much they are allowed to exists in by doing this.

```
android:layout_weight="your value here"
```

An example could be

```
android:layout_weight="0.2"
```

This is now allowed to fill 20% of the linearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can archive this by assigning LinearLayout Weights as try below code

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
    app:civ_border_width="5dp"
    app:civ_border="true"
    android:src="@drawable/user"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:weightSum="8">
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="StramTube"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="*"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="view"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="*"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hours ago"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_overflow_grey_24dp" />
```